# How enable the junk filter only in INBOX?

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

As the heading says: Is it possible (or at all necessary) to enable Thunderbird's junk filtering only in INBOX, i.e. disable it in all folders except INBOX?

Please note that I am not sure whether TB processes junk messages by default in every subfolder (hence the "or at all necessary" part in the sentence above). But if it does, I am concerned that it may move messages that I already have carefully sorted into my large and deeply nested hierarchy of subfolders to the junk folder without me knowing.

I really like TB's junk filter and think that it works very precisely (after long training, it currently misses 1 of 100 junk messages and marks 1 of 10000 non-junk messages as junk). Letting it run without letting it move junk messages to the junk folder automatically wouldn't make a lot sense for me, though. But as stated above, if I let it automatically move junk messages to the junk folder I am afraid that this happens to messages that I already have sorted into other folders, which would absolutely not be acceptable.

Therefore I have three questions:

- Does TB apply its junk filter in subfolders that are not in INBOX (e.g. public folders)?
- If yes, does it process messages that have been manually moved from INBOX into those folders?
- If yes, is it possible to alter the behavior so that the junk filter only operates on INBOX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is loaded into INBOX before filters move to your folders.

There is an action that can be set (from [Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125850) ) to stop rules you have set up to avoid the junk filter.

> Click Tools / Message Filters
> Double-click the filter that appears to be letting message go to "Junk"
> In the "Perform these actions" box, click the "+" on the right side of the last action
> Choose "Set Junk Status to" for the left box
> Choose "Not Junk" for the right box
> Click OK at the bottom
> Close the "Filter Rules" window

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, and +1. However, my concern was different. I'll explain by example. Let's assume the following: I receive a message `A` that is not classified as junk in this moment, and manually move that message into folder `f1`. Two days later, *I have trained the junk filter further, and message `A` would now be classified as junk if I would receive it again in identical form*. In that situation, could it happen that TB classifies message `A` **in folder `f1`** as junk and **moves it from folder `f1` into the junk folder**? If yes, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Once an email has been processed, it does not undergo any further manipulation unless you run the rule manually

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. This makes sense, and I believe you, so I accept your answer.